# What should we do with [glossary]?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, ambiguous-tags

[glossary](/questions/tagged/glossary) has eight questions (the last week I added it to three questions), no tag excerpt, and no wiki. The most prominent question having this tag is

[Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/289691)

NOTE: The referred tag was included on the above question since rev 1.

I have googled [site:stackexchange.com meta glossary] and look directly on some tag pages from other Meta sites, but I was not able to find site specific Meta with a tag named "glossary".

Should we add a tag excerpt to [glossary](/questions/tagged/glossary) even if it's only used on eight questions?

I think that it's worthy to mention that we have [terminology](/questions/tagged/terminology) which has 60 questions, a tag excerpt and tag wiki

---

[terminology](/questions/tagged/terminology)

Tag excerpt:

> The use or definition of a term in the context of Stack Exchange.

Tag wiki:

> Terminology, in the context of Stack Exchange, refers to the terms or other words/phrases that are used by the Stack Exchange site itself or that are used by its members in reference to the Stack Exchange network.
>
> This tag is not for describing context and identifying a word that fits it (aka a dictionary service). The terms should be directly related to Stack Exchange in some way.

---

The [Mi Yodeya Meta](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/) also has a [glossary tag](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glossary) but it hasn't a tag excerpt / wiki either. This tag has 5 questions.

Related

- [How do SE sites handle domain-specific jargon?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165656/289691)

Comment: One means to determine what a tag means is to look on another appropriate site, for the same tag; where there is no reason why the definition should be any different. Example: Stack Overflow tag [`glossary`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/glossary/info).

Comment: @Rob Unfortunately that particular example doesn't include tag usage guidelines and it doesn't exists on the corresponding meta.

Comment: The [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-m&ei=bOxCX4HIG4fZ-gSc9KnwBQ&q=site%3A*%2Ftags%2Fglossary%2Finfo&oq=site%3A*%2Ftags%2Fglossary%2Finfo) has [missed a few results](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5bglossary%5d&page=27); and your reason that it needs duplication on the lesser used child metas is orthogonal.

Answer (score 17):

I don't see why we need the tag [glossary](/questions/tagged/glossary) on Meta Stack Exchange. The term does have some technical use for linguistic corpus analysis, but *we are not doing any of that here*, and even if we somehow did, it would be such a rare occurrence that we wouldn't need a whole tag for it. Synonymize this tag with [terminology](/questions/tagged/terminology).

Comment: The term has other usages but I agree, it should be synonymized with [tag:terminology].

Comment: The last week I posted [Make \[glossary\] a synonym of \[terminology\]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353449/289691). So far the score is 8 (+8 / -0)... now I'm wondering if we could just replace [tag:glossary] by [tag:terminology]. What do you think?