# Make [glossary] a synonym of [terminology]

Tags: support, tags, meta, synonym-request

This was already discussed on [What should we do with [glossary]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353374/289691). There is only one answer which is proposing this, it has +15 / -0.

---

- [glossary](/questions/tagged/glossary) has 8 questions, no tag excerpt no tag wiki
- [terminology](/questions/tagged/terminology) has 60 questions, tag excerpt and tag wiki

While we already have [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/289691), here on Stack Exchange Meta  questions about glossaries are scarce and aren't very well received, 3 discussions questions have relative low scores

- [How do SE sites handle domain-specific jargon?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165656/289691) (score 8)
- [Can a tags list constitute a glossary?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213415/289691) (score 3)
- [Should we have a "glossary" of tag related terms coined by the community that are commonly used across SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353220/289691) (score 1)

The other questions having [glossary](/questions/tagged/glossary) rather than discussing a glossary are about Stack Exchange terms.